# Hints on parsing

Tags: parsing, templates

I want to implement a minimal templating language like Template Toolkit but much more simple.
I don't want to use an existing implementation/library, but start from scratch because I want to learn something from it and I want to completely understand it in order to adopt it to my needs.
The end product should be in C but I will probably try to make a prototype in Perl first.
For the beginning I only want it to handle including other files, substituting variables and, now comes the hard part, arbitrarily nestable if/elseif/else/endif-constructs which require some advanced parsing.

Here is an example illustrating its intended usage:

```
<h1>[% substitute title %]</h1>
<p>
[% if foo %]
foo is true
[% elseif bar %]
[% if baz %]
bar and baz are true
[% endif %]
bar is true
[% else %]
<em>none<em> is true
[% endif %]
</p>
```

I have decent C and some Perl skills but absolutely no knowledge in parsing, so I don't even know what exactly I am looking for.
So I would be interested in

- which algorithms can handle parsing like this
- reading recommendations on such algorithms, minimal introductions to parsing relevant here, or tutorials
- minimal, well documented/commented examples (I could not make much sense from TT source)

TIA.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using C, try (f)lex and yacc/bison. They are not that hard to use.

Besides there are several questions on the basics of compilers on SO.

Just the basics:

The first step is to translate the character stream to a token stream.

For example [% and %] are two tokens. But an identifier is also a token.

The next step, is to detect and execute the grammar. You can do this by building a syntax tree:

```
              [if]
             /  | \
            /   |  \
            |  Exp  |
            |   |   |
            |  foo  |
            |       |
      "foo is.."    elsif
                   / | \
                  /   |  \
                  |  Exp  |
                  |   |   |
                  |  bar  |
                  |       |
                  if      "none is true"
                /  | \
               /   |  \
               |  Exp  |
               |   |   |
               |  baz  |
               |       |
      "bar and..."    empty
```

And execute the tree. Which implies: for each (else)if node, evaluate the expression, and execute the true branch if true and the fase branch if false.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Would that be bootom-up parsing (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom-up_parsing)? I'm trying to get familiar with the concepts and terms so I can at least google stuff.

Comment: Note that what is shown in Gamecat's post is generally referred to as an AST (abstract syntax tree). When parsing, the token stream is typically converted into a parse tree first, *then* an AST.

Comment: @JG: Bottom-up parsing is a generic term for a certain type of parsing. If you want to learn the theory, it's probably best to start with top-down parsing (more specifically, recursive-descent).

Answer (score 0):

I've written a general answer to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292970/using-a-loop-in-a-template/1293434#1293434) some time before. Hopefuly, it can help you to find some starting point.

Answer (score 0):

[JavaCC](https://javacc.dev.java.net/) is the Java Compiler Compiler, its for making compilers in java.  Quite a useful bit of software if you want to make a programming language or interpreter.